# Have i installed the socks module in python?

Tags: python, package

list the packages beginnig at s.

```
pip list | grep ^s
setuptools           56.0.0
six                  1.12.0
sniffio              1.2.0
socks                0
```

Why the version number is zero?

```
python3
Python 3.9.6 (default, Jul 14 2021, 09:15:03) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import socks
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'socks'
debian@debian:~$  pip3  install socks
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: socks in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (0)
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.1.2; however, version 21.1.3 is available.
debian@debian:~$ python3
Python 3.9.6 (default, Jul 14 2021, 09:15:03) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import  socks
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'socks'
```

What is the matter with package----socks in my python?
`pip` might not be pointing to python3 ?

```
python3 -m pip list | grep ^s
selenium             3.141.0
setuptools           56.0.0
six                  1.16.0
sniffio              1.2.0
socks                0
```

Comment: You seem to have installed this: https://pypi.org/project/socks. It only has 1 released version, which is really "0": https://pypi.org/project/socks/0/#history. And installing it provides nothing: https://pypi.org/project/socks/0/#files. There is nothing to import. Check that you installed the correct package.

Comment: Are you sure `pip` is not the Python 2 version? If your Python ins `python3` then your `pip` would typically be `pip3`. Python 3 can't see packages you have only installed for Python 2, and vice versa.

Comment: `pip` might not be pointing to `python3`. what does `python3 -m pip list | grep ^s` return?

Answer (score -1):

If you're unsure you have socks installed, use:

> pip install socks

in the command prompt. That way it will either tell you that it's installed or install it for you

Comment: As OP mentioned, it is listed in [`pip list`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_list/), which "*lists installed packages*".